# Using npm, how do I globally install and use a "binary" package from a private repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a command line utility that I've written in node.js which has a "binary" it exposes via `package.json`'s `bin` property under the key `gogogo`.

I have it hosted on a private git repo. It is not registered on the npm registry. I realize we *could* do a private registry there, but I would prefer not to.

I'd like to be able to have others in my organization do:

`npm install -g git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.com:utils/setup.git`

and then once installed access it as one would with other global binaries by just typing:
`gogogo` into their shell (taking advantage of it being in the PATH).

The npm install above downloads and installs it into the global modules folder just fine, but I don't have a `gogogo` binary or symlink in my global modules folder. Do I have to `npm link`? I would really like to not have to do that.

Is there a way in the `npm install` to specify its global binary "alias"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does in fact work properly by just doing the normal:

`npm install -g git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.com:utils/setup.git`

I wasn't seeing my `gogogo` command in my path because I had previously done a `npm link` inside of my development folder which created a symlink in my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder to my dev folder. Once I removed the symlink `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/setup`, and reran the `npm install -g...` I was able to run `gogogo` from any path.